# less scientific or clinical sounding yet reassuring term for a gas that's okay to breathe than "breathable gas"?

Tags: phrase-requests

In the first sentence of the SE question [In simple terms, how does the way space suits manage breathable gas differ from how scuba gear does it?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53862/12102) I explain:

> I say "breathable gas" because what's in the tank can be a variety of mixtures and I don't know a single word for gas mixture you can safely breathe.

In the interest of biological and medical research and in deep sea diving and space exploration people have been give all kinds of gas mixtures with witch breathe to stay alive *and conscious*<sup>1</sup>. Sometimes pure oxygen, sometimes an oxygen-helium mix, etc.

The unifying feature would be to allow a *proper amount* of oxygen to the person's blood through the lungs, and otherwise "do no harm".

For water we have *[potable](https://www.lexico.com/definition/potable) water*. For air, we obviously have *breathable gas*.

But someone giving you a canister and saying "Here, inhale some of this. Trust me, it's breathable gas" doesn't sound reassuring.

**Question:** Is there a less scientific or clinical sounding yet reassuring term for a gas that's okay to breathe?

The phrase "[fit to breathe](https://www.lexico.com/definition/breathable) air" (perhaps with some hyphenation) is not scientific or clinical and apparently means the same as breathable. But is there a less awkward construction for that or something different and yet obvious?

---

<sup>1</sup>here I'm excluding [anesthetic mixutres](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/142519/16035) or things that have other adverse or impairing effects (e.g. tear gas and worse).

Comment: I think _inhalable_ would be somewhat "scientific" sounding. _Breathable_ works fine as an informal equivalent of _potable._

Comment: But, isn't 'potable' used for water? 'Breathable' sounds a little 'unwieldy' whereas 'inhalable' sounds easy.

Comment: @RamPillai "For water we have potable water." Yes.

Comment: Trust me, it’s ***harmless***

Comment: @Chappo Yes, I think this perfect answer is "ripe" for acceptance. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not a common term, the best description that encompasses both "normal" air as well as other gas mixtures that can safely sustain a person is ***breathing gas***.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breathing_gas) gives the following explanation:

> A breathing gas is a mixture of gaseous chemical elements and
> compounds used for respiration. Air is the most common, and only
> natural, breathing gas. But other mixtures of gases, or pure oxygen,
> are also used in breathing equipment and enclosed habitats such as
> scuba equipment, surface supplied diving equipment, recompression
> chambers, high-altitude mountaineering, high-flying aircraft,
> submarines, space suits, spacecraft, medical life support and first
> aid equipment, and anaesthetic machines.

Comment: Oh this works quite nicely! I don't know why I wasn't able to go from "breathable gas" to "breathing gas" by myself; it's exactly what's needed because (to me at least) it says "this gas is for breathing, you can breathe it and it will provide what you expect of a breathable gas".